# Customizing ionic slide pager dots into images

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, swiper.js

I am using ionic-slides for displaying pictures.
instead of the default pager dots, I want to display a preview of all the images on the bottom. 
just like how it shows on [here](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/23-thumbs-gallery.html)
How can you achieve this two-way control carausol in ionic2-angular4?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box slider control like that on `Ionic`.But Ionic has used `Swiper.js` for their component.So you need to create custom slider control using `Swiper.js`.

You can get help from [**official swiper doc here**](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WajbHrIjHIU).

Here you can see how to develop [**Angular slider control using Swiper.js**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper).